# C# if else shortcut

Tags: c#

In C# how can I express the following if else statement using a shorter method(with ?):

```
 if (condition1 == true && count > 6)
           {
               dothismethod(value);

           }
           else if (condition2 == false)
           {

               dothismethod(value);
           }
```

My code looks really messy with these statements. Can someone direct me to a good resource on if then else short cut syntax?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It sounds like you're trying to write

```
if ((condition1 && count > 6) || !condition2)
    SomeMethod();
```

Answer (score 9):

`?` is not a "shortcut" if/else. It's called a **ternary operator**, and it's used when you want to assign a value to some variable based on a condition, like so:

`string message = hasError ? "There's an error!" : "Everything seems fine...";`

MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Answer (score 4):

Your can write it like:

```
if ((condition1 == true && count > 6) || condition2 == false)
{
    dothismethod(value);
}
```

But personally, I would define your first expression as another variable, so your if statement becomes clearer:

```
bool meaningfulConditionName = (condition1 == true) && count > 6;
if (meaningfulConditionName || !condition2)
{
    dothismethod(value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The conditional operator `?` only works for value assignment. But you can definitely fold both if's into one since the result is the same for both:

```
if ((condition1 == true && count > 6) || condition2 == false)
           {
               dothismethod(value);
           }
```

Or even more concise as:

```
if ((condition1 && count > 6) || !condition2) dothismethod(value);
```